# How to take array values within json data in react native?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, array-map

Hello I'm trying to render a fetch response from server like the following

```
.then(responseData => {
                responseData.map(detail => {

                    let currIndex = -1;
                    let k = detail.data.curriculum.reduce((acc, curr) => {

                        if (curr.type === 'section') {
                            acc.push({
                                title: curr.title,
                                content: [],
                                id: []
                            })
                            currIndex += 1
                        } else {
                            acc[currIndex].content.push(curr.title);
                            acc[currIndex].id.push(curr.id);
                        }

                        return acc;
                    }, []);
                    console.log(k)
                    this.setState({ k })
                });
            });
```

I'm trying to render a UI like this

[image]

But what I'm getting is the name of video contents will be listed one after the other as a list like this

[image]

The corresponding code I've tried so far is as below

**code**

```
 <Content padder style={{ backgroundColor: "#f4f4f4" }}>

                        {this.state.k.map(detail =>

                            <View style={st.card}>
                                <View style={st.cardHeading}>
                                    <Text style={st.headingText}>{detail.title}</Text>
                                </View>

                                <ScrollView
                                    horizontal
                                    style={st.cardBody}>

                                    <View style={st.videoContent}>
                                        <View style={st.videoImage}>
                                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="play-circle-outline" size={25} color="#fff" />
                                        </View>
                                        <Text style={st.subheadingText}>{detail.content}</Text>
                                    </View>

                                </ScrollView>

                            </View>
                        )}
</Content
```

>

The json data within this.state.k is as follows.I'm trying to render the Title as `headingText` and content as `videoContent`.Please help me to find a solution.
[image]

Comment: Not sure about your code. Method MAP returns new array, so you have not set state in each MAP iteration, but convert element and return new one. So the result of MAP function will be new array with mapped elements. like:

const originalArray = [0,1,2,3,4]

const newArray = originalArray.map( (element) => { return element +1} )

And newArray will be [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: I want the `content` within as a new array and should map over that `content`.How do I do  that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are missing is to actually loop through the content or id arrays inside the `ScrollView` element. Based on your current data structure, I would suggest doing something like this.

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal
  style={st.cardBody}
>
  {detail.content.map((contentValue, i) => (
    <View style={st.videoContent}>
      <View style={st.videoImage}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name="play-circle-outline"
          size={25}
          color="#fff"
        />
      </View>

      <Text style={st.subheadingText}>
        Title: { contentValue }
        Id: { detail.id[i] }
      </Text>
    </View>
  ))}
</ScrollView>
```

Note that I added the value from the `id` array inside the `Text` element, both to illustrate how to access it, but also to show that the data structure makes this quite cumbersome so it might be better to improve that structure, possible like this

```
.then(responseData => {
  responseData.map(detail => {
    let currIndex = -1;
    const k = detail.data.curriculum.reduce((acc, curr) => {

      if (curr.type === 'section') {
        acc.push({
            title: curr.title,
            content: []
        })
        currIndex += 1

      } else {
        acc[currIndex].content.push(curr);
      }

      return acc;
    }, []);

    this.setState({ k })
  });
});
```

That way you don't have to keep track of the index of the array when mapping and can simple use it like this

```
  {detail.content.map((curr) => (
    ...
      <Text style={st.subheadingText}>
        Title: { curr.title }
        Id: { curr.id }
      </Text>
    ...
  ))}
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)